# Android WhatsApp image sharing

Tags: android, sharing, whatsapp

I am developing an application in which i have to share image and text on **WhatsApp** with in my application.

Is there any best way to do that.

I am capturing my application screen, and need to send that image via **WhatsApp**

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After Spending some time I am able to share Image and Text to whatsapp from my application using this code :

```
String smsNumber = "91xxxxxxxxxx"; //without '+'
    try {
        Uri imageUri = null;
        try {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whatsapp_image), null, null));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "App - Link");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Happy Coding :)